# MDX - CHILDREN doesn't return any values, MEMBERS do

Tags: ssas, mdx

I used the following expression in MDX:

```
SELECT
null ON 0,
[dim].[hier].CHILDREN ON 1
FROM [Cube]
```

It did not return any values. However, when I issued

```
SELECT
null ON 0,
[dim].[hier].[hier].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Cube]
```

It worked. What is interesting, yesterday first query was working too, so I suspect some cube change might've caused that, however I don`t have an access so I cannot check it.

Is there some subtle difference between CHILDREN and MEMBERS which causes that bahaviour? I thought the two are similar except for the fact that CHILDREN digs one level down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the exact semantic of [CHILDREN](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Children.html) in case you apply it to a non-member; i.e., not sure it is implemented as [MEMBERS](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Members.html). But to reply to this sentence :

> CHILDREN digs one level down

no; children returns the children of the member it is applied to. Those children does not necessarily belong to the next level down. In case of a [ragged hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365406.aspx), the children could be several levels down.

Answer (score 0):

it is not working cause of this:
Do not Forget on this brackets {} >> which bounds the couple on a row (on 1)

```
SELECT NON EMPTY AddCalculatedMembers  ( { [member name].[].[].&[]&[].children, [member name].[].[].&[1]&[].children } )  on 1, [Measures].[Sales] on 0 FROM [Cube Name];
```